# equivalent expression for converge to zero almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

In Durret's [Probabilty:Theory and Example](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTEv5a.pdf) p61, It said:

$X_{n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely iff for all $\epsilon>0$, $Pr(\lvert X_{n} \rvert > \epsilon$ infinitely often $)=0$

May anyone kindly  to explain why the two expression are equivalent?

Comment: I don't see where on page 61 the quoted line appears.

Comment: in line 9  "An example which illustrates the use of this notation is...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{as}{\text{ a.s. }}\newcommand{io}{\text{ i.o. }}$The book doesn't say that. It says

> $X_n\to 0\as$ if and only if for all $\varepsilon>0$, $$P(\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon\io)=0$$

Which means that $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely if and only if for all $\varepsilon>0$ the measure of the set $A_\varepsilon:=\{\omega\,:\, \lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert>\varepsilon\text{ for infinitely many values of }n\}$ is $0$. Many authors would indicate $A_\varepsilon$ with the notation $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{\omega\,:\, \lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert>\varepsilon\}$, in which case the general rule is \begin{align}\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n&:=\{y\,:\, y\in A_n\io\}\\ \liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n&:=\{y\,:\, \exists N,\forall n\ge N,\ y\in A_n\}\end{align}

---

**After edit:** If you look at definitions, $\bigcup\limits_{\varepsilon >0}A_\varepsilon$ is *exactly* the set of those points $\omega$ such that $X_n(\omega)\not\to 0$. For, what's the negation of "*for all* $\varepsilon>0$*,* $\lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert\le\varepsilon$ *eventually*"? It's "*there is some* $\varepsilon>0$ *such that* $\lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert>\varepsilon$ *frequently*". Now, it is clear that $\bigcup_{\varepsilon >0}A_\varepsilon$ is actually a countable union (because you can just consider $\varepsilon\in\Bbb Q$), and that it's a nul set if and only if all the $A_\varepsilon$ are.

Comment: Sorry, it is typo. I miss the "=0" in quote. May you give some hints about why the two description are quivalent?

Comment: It seems the "only if" part is easier but the "if" part is not obvious to me.

Comment: I mean, if you look at definitions, $\bigcup_{\varepsilon >0}A_\varepsilon$ is *exactly* the set of points such that $X_n(\omega)\not\to 0$.